# Windows Azure access POST data

Tags: asp.net, wcf, post, azure

Ok, so I can't seem to find decent Windows Azure examples. I have a simple hello world application that's based on [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlem/archive/2010/04/26/wcf-rest-and-url-rewriting-with-windows-azure.aspx). I want to have custom output instead of JSON or XML. So I created my interface like:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "session/create", Method = "POST")]
    string createSession();
}

public class MyService : IService
{
    public string createSession()
    {
        // get access to POST data here: user, pass
        string sessionid = Session.Create(user, pass);
        return "sessionid=" + sessionid;
    }
}
```

For the life of me, I can't seem to figure out how to access the `POST` data. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Which protocol is your service using?

Comment: I am using HTTP protocol, `WebServiceHostFactory` as the HostFactory.

Comment: Just a sidenote, creating a session ID you may want to make sure the pass has a timestamp element so you get a different session ID every time. Also incorporating the user with the pass will make sure the pass is different for each user (if you didnt want to include the timestamp).

Comment: @Russel, the session.create code is just to say "a user has logged in successfully, and here's the sessionid" it's just an outline/stub and not actual code. I just need to know how to get user/pass variables populated from POST data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an HttpContext there may be a Request object that would have the form data.  I'm basing part of this off the ASP.Net tag on this question, so if that is incorrect then there may be the need to handle this another way but it looks a lot like a web service to my mind.

---

EDIT: [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) is the class that has the Form property that should be where the POST data is stored if this is an HTTP request.  This is part of System.Web so it should be ready to be used pretty easily, as I recall.

---

[Sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) showing the Request.Form property:

```
int loop1;
NameValueCollection coll;

//Load Form variables into NameValueCollection variable.
coll=Request.Form;
// Get names of all forms into a string array.
String[] arr1 = coll.AllKeys;
for (loop1 = 0; loop1 < arr1.Length; loop1++) 
{
    Response.Write("Form: " + arr1[loop1] + "<br>");
}
```

This presumed there was an HttpRequest instance around.

---

[WCF Simplified Part 4: Comparing the Request/Reply and One-Way Patterns](https://soumya.wordpress.com/2010/05/25/wcf-simplified-part-4-comparing-the-requestreply-and-one-way-patterns/) passes in a parameter so that your "createSession" method would have to take in those strings it would appear.  I'm used to the ASP.Net world where there are some built-in objects like Request, Response, Server, Application and Session.

---

Yes, if you did try changing the method signature as there are ways to pass in parameters in that last example I linked though I don't know if that would work in your case or not.

Comment: I think this is actually a WCF service from the looks of it.  I added the WCF tag.

Comment: @smartx, Thank you. That was a typo.
@JB King, Not sure how I'd get access to HttpContext, I don't think I'm using ASP.NET at all. But I'm not really sure, I just followed the tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlem/archive/2010/04/26/wcf-rest-and-url-rewriting-with-windows-azure.aspx

Comment: @JB King, please show me sample code in the context of my sample code above. Look at the comment where it says `get access to POST data here: user, pass` - I created a bounty to make it worth your time.

Comment: @JB King, where would I find the `HttpRequest` instance? Please tell me how to access `POST` data inside the `createSession()` function above.

Comment: Thank you JB King! I will give you the bounty for this question. So in other words, your answer is that there is no way to do this in WCF syntax.